# how to find whether the cron timeout or error in cron job?

Tags: php, cron

I fetch some data from the remote server and feed it into my site database .It has 900k of records(app) but the insertion of records stopped 60,180 records only. We use `mailto`  and an exception handler to find the bugs but no response.

Can anyone offer advice on how to get the cron  timeout or do we have an error in code our code?

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort();
try
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  // set URL and other appropriate options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ks329xxx.com/cronRU/update");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  // grab URL and pass it to the browser
  curl_exec($ch);

  // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
  curl_close($ch);
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
  echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  mail('varunxxxx@xxxxx.com', 'update', $message);  
}
?>
```

Comment: I edited your post a little - whenever someone mentions a [lakh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) it causes confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking for the result of `curl_exec()`:

```
if (curl_exec($ch) === false) {
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}
```